# drupal--why $node->taxonomy is an array

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, loops, drupal-6

someone wrote this code.

```
 foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
 $tids[] = 't.tid = %d';
  $args[] = $term->tid;
 }
```

how he knows that in foreach "$node->taxonomy" is an array? and when i loop it,
foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
}
the output that i get will be the $term's value. i don't know how it is change into the 't.tid = %d' and $term->tid. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal-related code, a `$node` is almost always an object produced by the [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6) function. Since every module has the opportunity to add its own properties to this object, it's very hard to find a central documentation of these properties.

By experience and by variable inspection, seasoned Drupal developers know that when set `$node->taxonomy` is always an array of term object (as returned by the [`taxonomy_get_term()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term/6) function) indexed by their respective ids (named tids, for Term ID). This array is set by the [`taxonomy_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_nodeapi/6) function when `$op == 'load'` and is produced by the [`taxonomy_get_terms()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_get_terms/6) function.

The question give little information but we can guess that the loop is meant to build two arrays used to generate a database query that filter on the tid column matching those of the `$node` object. Because the terms' data is already stored in the items of `$node->taxonomy`, let's hope that this query is not used to re-load the terms to display some of their name and/or description. Collecting 't.tid = %d' is probably a bad idea, the query would be better build with a single `"tid in (". db_placeholder($args) .")"` WHERE clause after collecting all the tids in `$args`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear. All Items under the node object are arrays. You can check it yourself bu using:

```
print_r($node);
die;
```

Or using any PHP debugger.

for the foreach, It is very simple foreach... I don't understand what is the problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

t.tid is simply an SQL query. %d is a placeholder for $args[], which consists of $term->tid. It's like this structure: [PDO connections](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).